# How to avoid having to enter image version in deployment yaml and use most recent image from azure container registry

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to deploy an app to AKS cluster. Everytime I push changes to my branch, I want AKS to redeploy pods and make use of the most recent tag (which I have versioned with $(Build.BuildId))

The problem is right now I have to manually retrieve this build version and enter it into deployment.yaml and then run `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` for the change to go ahead. For example, the most recent tag is 58642, so I would have to log into my Azure Container Registry, retrieve the version number, update the deployment.yaml, and then apply for changes to take effect.

How can I change my setup here so that the most recently built and tagged container is deployed to the AKS cluster as part of my CICD?

Here is my `deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mission-model-api
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mission-model-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mission-model-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mission-model-api
        image: my_registry.azurecr.io/serving/mission_model_api:58642
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mission-model-api
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: mission-model-api
```

And here is my CI/CD `azure-pipelines.yaml`

```
variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  envName: 'poc-releases'
  docker_image_name: API
  imagePullSecret: 'AUTH'
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'XX'

trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - feature/*

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  pool:
    vmImage: $(vmImageName)
  jobs:
    - job: Build
      displayName: Build job
      variables:
        PROJECT_DIR: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/apps/$(docker_image_name)
        IMAGE_AND_TAG: "$(docker_image_name):$(tag)"
      steps:
        - script: |
            az acr login --name my_registry.azurecr.io --username user --password $(acr_password)
          displayName: ACR Login
        - bash: >
            docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t "$(IMAGE_AND_TAG)" .
          displayName: Build docker image
          workingDirectory: $(PROJECT_DIR)
        - script: |
            REGISTRY_PATH=my_registry.azurecr.io/serving
            docker tag "$(IMAGE_AND_TAG)" "$REGISTRY_PATH/$(IMAGE_AND_TAG)"
            docker push "$REGISTRY_PATH/$(IMAGE_AND_TAG)"
          displayName: Tag and Push to ACR
        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
          inputs:
            artifact: 'manifests'
            artifactName: 'manifests'
            targetPath: '$(PROJECT_DIR)/manifests'

- stage: Deploy_BVT
  displayName: Deploy BVT
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy_BVT
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: '$(envName).ingress-basic'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@1
            inputs:
              artifactName: 'manifests'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests'
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Create imagePullSecret
            inputs:
              action: createSecret
              secretName: $(imagePullSecret)
              namespace: ingress-basic
              dockerRegistryEndpoint: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: deploy
              namespace: "ingress-basic"
              manifests: |
                $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/cluster-isseur.yaml
                $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/deployment.yaml
                $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/ingress.yaml
              imagePullSecrets: |
                $(imagePullSecret)
              containers: |
                "$REGISTRY_PATH/$(docker_image_name):$(tag)"
```

Comment: Do you have a build job on a Jenkins server that can poll the scm to detect the change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace tokens task can solve your problem. I use it most of the time.

1. For the deployment yaml, change the image like this.

> ```
> image: my_registry.azurecr.io/serving/mission_model_api:#{Build.BuildId}#
> ```

2. Before the **task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0** task in **Build** stage, put a **[Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)** task. You should add it as an extension to Azure DevOps

> ```
> - task: replacetokens@4
>   inputs:
>     targetFiles: '**/deployment.yml'
>     encoding: 'auto'
>     tokenPattern: 'default'
>     writeBOM: true
>     actionOnMissing: 'warn'
>     keepToken: false
>     actionOnNoFiles: 'continue'
>     enableTransforms: false
>     useLegacyPattern: false
>     enableTelemetry: true
> ```

Then it should work as you expected.